# How to use pastespecial with End(xlUp)

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I am currently having an issue getting the data from one sheet to paste special into another sheet, I am trying to consolidate multiple files (same headers, differing number of rows) into one master sheet containing all the rows. At the moment I'm doing that by opening all the files, pulling in the tabs I want, copy and pasting the data, and then deleting the tabs.  Yes I am sure there is an easier way, but I'm very new to VBA and am learning on the fly..here's what I have so far:

```
Sub ConsolidateSheets()

' open each file in folder
Dim Folder As String
Dim Files As String
Folder = "C:\Users\212411103\Documents\Risk Project Tracker\Risk Project Tracker Monthly\Monthly Data"
Files = Dir(Folder & "\*.xls")
Do While Files <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Folder & "\" & Files
Files = Dir
Loop

' pull in Risk Project Tracker tab from each file to new workbook

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim sWksName As String

sWksName = "Risk Project Tracker"
For Each wkb In Workbooks
If wkb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
    wkb.Worksheets(sWksName).Copy _
      Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
End If
Next
Set wkb = Nothing

Dim J As Integer

' add new sheet for combined data

On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "New Month"

' paste headers from first two rows into new sheet "New Month"

Sheets(2).Select
Range("A1:AH2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("New Month").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select

' work through sheets
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count ' from sheet 2 to last sheet
Sheets(J).Activate ' make the sheet active
Rows("1:2").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Range("A1:AH500").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("New Month").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select

Next

' Delete tabs that are no longer needed i.e. the tabs from the 17 files

' For Each ws in Sheets
' Application.DisplayAlerts=False
' If ws.Name <> "New Month" Then ws.delete
' Next
' Application.DisplayAlerts=True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific issue you are having?  It is nearly impossible to look at functioning code and spot problems.  Please [edit] your question with a little more detail on that front.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the primary reason you are specifying the [Range .PasteSpecial method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) is the carry-over of column widths which is done for every tab. Perhaps cycling through A:AH once and setting the column widths should be sufficient.

```
Sub ConsolidateSheets2()
    Dim fldr As String, fn As String, sWksName As String, sNewWksName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wkb As Workbook

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    sWksName = "Risk Project Tracker"
    fldr = "C:\Users\212411103\Documents\Risk Project Tracker\Risk Project Tracker Monthly\Monthly Data"
    fn = Dir(fldr & "\*.xls")
    sNewWksName = "New Month"

    With ThisWorkbook
        Do While fn <> ""
            Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fldr & Chr(92) & fn)
            If IsObject(wkb.Worksheets(sWksName)) Then
                wkb.Worksheets(sWksName).Copy _
                    Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1 - CBool(Sheets(1).Name = sNewWksName))
                On Error GoTo bm_Need_New_Month_ws
                With .Worksheets(sNewWksName)
                    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
                    .Parent.Sheets(2).Range("A3:AH502").Copy _
                        Destination:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End With
            End If
            wkb.Close False
            fn = Dir
        Loop
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Do While Sheet.Count > 1: Sheets(2).Delete: Loop
    End With

    GoTo bm_Safe_Exit

bm_Need_New_Month_ws:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1))
            .Name = sNewWksName
            .Move Before:=Sheets(1)
            .Parent.Sheets(2).Range("A1:AH2").Copy _
                Destination:=.Range("A1")
            For c = .Columns("AH:AH").Column To 1 Step -1
                .Columns(c).ColumnWidth = _
                    .Parent.Sheets(2).Columns(c).ColumnWidth
            Next c
        End With
        Resume
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```